# fixed positioning bug on Android chrome

Tags: android, ios, css, google-chrome, mobile

So I have a simple flash message on our site, which should have fixed positioning in the bottom left.  On mobile, I've also added a width of 100% to make it look a little nicer, with a small amount of padding to offset it from the edges.

The container for these flash messages is in the root of the body:

```
#FlashMessages-Container {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 550px;
    padding: 32px;
    z-index: 11;

  @include media-down(large) {
    max-width: 57%;
  }

  @include media-down(medium) {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
  }
}
```

This works great on desktop on all browsers, and also works great on mobile Android/Firefox, iOS/Safari and even iOS/Chrome.  *However*, it doesn't work on Android Chrome, which doesn't calculate the width correctly.  You can see from this DevTools screenshot, it's making the flash messages 376px wide when the screen "width" is only 360px (device pixels, that is), so there is no gap on the right side.

If I make the position absolute, the width is correct but then it's not fixed.

Here is the offending Android/Chrome view:

[image: Galaxy S9/Android/Chrome]

The related dev tools styles:

[image: dev tools]

---

And here is Android/Firefox which looks fine:

[image: Galaxy S9/Android/Firefox]

Here's iOS/Firefox too:

[image: iPhone 8 Plus/iOS/Safari]

And finally, even iOS/Chrome which strangely works fine unlike its Android cousin.

[image: iPhone 8 Plus/iOS/Chrome]